# why is it now acceptable to say "what do you think TO that" rather than "ABOUT that"?

Tags: usage

Why is it now accepted to say "what do think TO that" instead of "ABOUT" that, as we were taught in grammar lessons?

Comment: Is TO a typo of OF?

Comment: Also, *you* missing.

Comment: "what do think to that" is ungrammatical. Please give some context for where you've heard it. Also "why is this so?" questions are hard to answer for languages.

Comment: @starsplusplus "I'm the man who murdered love / Yeah! What do you think to that?"  http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/xtc/imthemanwhomurderedlove.html

Answer (score 4):

It's colloquial British English. 'what do you think to that' means the same thing as 'what do you think of/ about that'. It's considered obsolete or rare, although you may find it in some regions of England.

Comment: but are we sure he means 'what do you think to that' or it's 'what do think TO that'. He has capitalized both the letters and it's unlikely that a person makes a mistake there.

Comment: Considering that he also capitalized ABOUT, that seems to be looking for a very remote possibility. He inadvertently left out the "you", the all-caps is just for emphasis.

Comment: I agree with Jolenealaska.